# How to set initial zoom slide value based on image in cropper js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var src,
range_ratio_value;

jQuery( "#zoom-slider" ).slider();

jQuery('#photo').change(function() {
var file_data = jQuery('#photo').prop('files')[0];
var cropper_image = jQuery('.cropper_image');
var reader = new FileReader();
jQuery(reader).load(function(e) {
    src = e.target.result;
    cropper_image.attr('src', src);
});
reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);

setTimeout(function() {
    var cropper_url = cropper_image[0];
    cropper_image.attr('src', src);
    var new_image = cropper_image[0];
    var cropper = new Cropper( new_image, {
        aspectRatio: 1,
        viewMode: 0,                // zoom as free
        guides: false,              // hide guid lines
        dragMode: 'move',           // dragging mode of cropper
        movable: true,              // enable image move
        cropBoxMovable: false,      // crop box move disable
        cropBoxResizable: false,    // crop box resize disable
        minCropBoxWidth: 300,
        minCropBoxHeight: 300,
        maxCropBoxWidth: 300,
        maxCropBoxHeight: 300,
        zoomOnWheel: false,
        ready: function(e) {
            var cropper_slide = this.cropper;
            range_ratio_value = jQuery('#range_ratio_value');

            imageData = cropper.getImageData();
            containerData = cropper.getContainerData();
            cropBoxData = cropper.getCropBoxData();
            // var minSliderZoom = imageData.width / imageData.naturalWidth;
            var minSliderZoom = (imageData.naturalWidth - imageData.width) / imageData.width;

            var aspectRatio = cropBoxData.width / cropBoxData.height;
            console.log(aspectRatio);
            // cropper_slide.zoomTo(0.90);

            jQuery(".cr-slider-wrap").show();
            // jQuery("#zoom-slider").slider("option", "max", cropBoxData.width + 100);
            // jQuery("#zoom-slider").slider("option", "min", cropBoxData.width);
            jQuery("#zoom-slider").slider("value", 0);
            range_ratio_value.val('0');
        },
        zoom: function(e){
            // console.log(e);
            // var ratio = Math.round(e.ratio * 1000)/10;
            // $dataZoom.text(ratio);
        }
    });

    //cropper UI sliders
    jQuery('#zoom-slider').slider({
        min: 0.1,
        max: 4,
        value: 0,
        step: 0.01,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            if (cropper){
                imageData = cropper.getImageData();
                var crop_box = cropper.getCropBoxData();
                var currentValue = jQuery("#zoom-slider").slider("value");
                console.log(range_ratio_value.val(), ui.value, imageData, crop_box);

                // if ((imageData.width < crop_box.width || imageData.height < crop_box.height) && (Number(range_ratio_value.val()) > ui.value)) {
                //     console.log('set min level');
                //     return false;
                // } else {
                    cropper.zoomTo(ui.value);
                    slide_width = jQuery('#zoom-slider .ui-slider-handle');
                    console.log(slide_width);
                    if(jQuery('.slide_fill_color').length > 0) {
                        // return false;
                        jQuery('.slide_fill_color').css({'width': slide_width + '%'});
                    }
                    else {
                        jQuery('#zoom-slider').append('<div class="slide_fill_color"></div>');
                        jQuery('.slide_fill_color').css({'width': slide_width + 'px'});
                    }
                // }
                range_ratio_value.val(ui.value);
            }
        }
    });
}, 1000);
});
});
```

```css
.cropper_headshot_box {
                width: 500px;
                height: 500px;
            }
            img {
                max-width: 100%;
            }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.0.0-rc.1/cropper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.0.0-rc.1/cropper.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" class="file_input" accept="image/*"/>
</form>

<div class="cropper_headshot_box" id="cropper_headshot">
    <img class="cropper_image" src=""/>

    <div>
        <input type="hidden" id="range_ratio_value" value=""/>
        <div id="zoom-slider"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="slider-val-area">
                <span id="min-zoom-val" class="pull-left">0</span>
            </div>
            <div class="slider-val-area">
                <span id="max-zoom-val" class="pull-right">1</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When i slide the cropper js image the image slide starts with initial value. By the initial, the image set to fit by the canvas container.

Can any one help to set slider value as based on image. Because, when i slide, the image starts with initial zoom value. But, i need to zoom in/out as image show position.